# Local crash at /system/lib/libwebcore.so file

Tags: android, webview, android-ndk, android-webview, segmentation-fault

I have a problem with Android 4.3. My app contains **webview** and it crashes at only **Android 4.3** .I don't understand what is the problem and how to solve it. Here is the crash report:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/m0xx/m0:4.3/JSS15J/I9300XXUGNG3:user/release-keys'
Revision: '12'
pid: 21590, tid: 21692, name: WebViewCoreThre  >>> org.uusoftware.burclar <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
    r0 61a8187c  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 5fc94118
    r4 61a8187c  r5 5f834a85  r6 00000000  r7 61a818b4
    r8 00000000  r9 5b68f3d8  sl 00000000  fp 00000000
    ip 00000001  sp 61a81848  lr 5f870aa5  pc 5f5e2a56  cpsr 08000030
    d0  0000000000000418  d1  0000000000000000
    d2  0000000000000000  d3  41d639a123dd2dba
    d4  3f947ae147ae147b  d5  3fa9bbd000000000
    d6  3ff0000000000000  d7  4090600000000000
    d8  41d639a123dd0cfe  d9  41d639a123e04031
    d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    d16 0000000000000000  d17 0000000000000000
    d18 411bd3b000000000  d19 3febc47803b137c3
    d20 3febc47803b137c3  d21 4024000000000000
    d22 0000000000000000  d23 4020000000000000
    d24 4059000000000000  d25 4030000000000000
    d26 4041800000000000  d27 4059000000000000
    d28 4034000000000000  d29 4059000000000000
    d30 3fe0000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
    scr 68000097

backtrace:
    #00  pc 00107a56  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #01  pc 00395aa1  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #02  pc 00395c4f  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #03  pc 0016ca77  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #04  pc 002dde93  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #05  pc 004d46df  /system/lib/libwebcore.so
    #06  pc 00000158  <unknown>

code around pc:
    5f5e2a34 6001b909 a801e009 fb20f7ff a8019b01  
    5f5e2a44 92012200 f7fd6023 4620fc2c b513bd1c  
    5f5e2a54 68094604 6001b909 a801e009 f8def7ff  
    5f5e2a64 a8019b01 92012200 f7fd6023 4620fc1a  
    5f5e2a74 b513bd1c 68094604 6001b909 a801e009  
    5f5e2a84 f9d2f7ff a8019b01 92012200 f7fd6023  
    5f5e2a94 4620fc08 b513bd1c 68094604 6001b909  
    5f5e2aa4 a801e009 fda6f7fe a8019b01 92012200  
    5f5e2ab4 f7fd6023 4620fbf6 b513bd1c 68094604  
    5f5e2ac4 6001b909 a801e009 fd3df7fe a8019b01  
    5f5e2ad4 92012200 f7fd6023 4620fbe4 b513bd1c  
    5f5e2ae4 68094604 6001b909 a801e009 f89ff7ff  
    5f5e2af4 a8019b01 92012200 f7fd6023 4620fbd2  
    5f5e2b04 b513bd1c 68094604 6001b909 a801e009  
    5f5e2b14 fa02f7ff a8019b01 92012200 f7fd6023  
    5f5e2b24 4620fbc0 b513bd1c 68094604 6001b909  

code around lr:
    5f870a84 f56e4620 4620fe00 0000bd10 447b4b01  
    5f870a94 47706818 0046027e 4604b510 ffd7f571  
    5f870aa4 bd104620 f6f74608 b57fbbd7 69964602  
    5f870ab4 68452400 7d006903 ac046194 6d04f844  
    5f870ac4 0011e88d f1024608 320c0108 462047a8  
    5f870ad4 f97ef5d6 0000bd7f b5104b0a 4604447b  
    5f870ae4 f8403308 f5d63b18 f104f973 f571000c  
    5f870af4 f104ff96 f5710008 4620ff92 fe20f7d5  
    5f870b04 bd104620 00421fbc 4604b510 ffe4f7ff  
    5f870b14 f56e4620 4620fdb8 b530bd10 2400b085  
    5f870b24 68059809 ac046004 46114608 5d04f844  
    5f870b34 9400461a 3020f89d fc9cf6f7 f5d64620  
    5f870b44 b005f947 b510bd30 b1304604 ff67f571  
    5f870b54 e8bd4620 f1624010 bd10bb87 460fb5f8  
    5f870b64 447d4d0a b984682c f56b2004 4606eaa0  
    5f870b74 60306838 fd25f56e f7ff4620 602effe4
```

This error only happens at Android 4.3 and only occurs on **Samsung phones** (mostly Galaxy S3 sometimes Note2 and Note3) while users are at webview fragment. Here is the my code of the fragment:

```
    public class FragmentFifth extends Fragment {

    String link;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fifth, container, false);

        link = "some url link";

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView0);
        myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl(link);

        return v;
    }
```